# How to write a kotlin data class to match json?

Tags: json, kotlin, data-class

I am using Retrofit to call API and using converter-gson to convert response json to kotlin

This is response

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "rank": "1",
    "name": "Challenge",
    "status": "E",
    "createDate": "2018-09-17 15:01:28",
    "lastModDate": "2018-09-17 15:06:32",
    "category": "DINING",
    "photo": {
        "path": "http://example.com/xxx.jpg",
        "size": [
            400,
            267
        ]
    }
}
```

And this is data class.

```
data class ServiceList (val id:Int,
                        val rank:Int,
                        val name:String,
                        val status:String,
                        val lastModDate:String,
                        val category:String,
                        ???????)
```

How to complete this class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare another `data class` to describe the `photo` property like so:

```
data class ServiceList(val id: Int,
                       val rank: Int,
                       val name: String,
                       val status: String,
                       val lastModDate: String,
                       val category: String,
                       val photo: Photo) {
    data class Photo(val size: List<Int>, val path: String)
}
```

If the `Photo` is to be used in other contexts as well you can pull it out to be a top level class:

```
data class ServiceList (val id: Int,
                        val rank: Int,
                        val name: String,
                        val status: String,
                        val lastModDate: String,
                        val category: String,
                        val photo: ServiceListPhoto)

data class ServiceListPhoto(val size: List<Int>, val path: String)
```